# ¿Hacer una ventana modal correctamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy aprendiendo `MVC` en `aspx, chtml y c#`, y llegué a la parte que muestro los detalles de un alumno pero primero lo hice que copiara la misma estructura de mi `Layout` y ahora lo que quiero es mostrar una ventana modal de `Ver Detalle`. Sé que tengo que hacer una vista parcial para que mande a llamar lo que muestra y pasarlo a un div, pero no sé muy bien. ¿Cómo le tendría que hacer a lo demás?

Answer (score 2):

Exacto es como lo comentas, renderizas el partialview y lo inyectas en el div que forma parte del popup de jquery dialog

[Render Partial View inside jQuery Dialog Modal Popup on Top of Parent View in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Render-Partial-View-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-on-Top-of-Parent-View-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Muy importante como usa `$.ajax` el cual invoca al action que retorna el partialview

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/Details",
    data: '{customerId: "' + customerId + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        $('#dialog').html(response);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

puntualizando en el `success` que es donde inyecta el render de la view en el div

```
$('#dialog').html(response);
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```